# I want to make selectable only those td where unselectable="off"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am creating a room reservation system. So i want to make selectable only those td where unselectable="off". Please help me do this.

This is my html code and here is my script that I am using to select them.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "table" ).selectable(
    {
        filter: 'tbody td unselectable:off '
    }
    );
});
</script>
```

But nothing is happening.
Please help me out with this problem.

```
            <tr>
                <td unselectable="on" resource="B" style="width: 79px; border-right: 1px solid #000000;
                    border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #ECE9D8;
                    font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 8pt; color: #000000; cursor: default;">
                    <div unselectable="on" style="margin-left: 4px; height: 19px; line-height: 19px;
                        overflow: hidden;">
                        Room B</div>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" unselectable="on" style="width: 1px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                    background-color: #FFF4BC;">
                    <div unselectable="on" style="position: relative; height: 19px; overflow: none;">
                        <div unselectable="on" onclick="javascript:event.cancelBubble=true;alert('2');" style="position: absolute;
                            left: 200px; top: -1px; width: 398px; height: 19px; border: 1px solid #000000;
                            background-color: #FFFFFF; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; font-family: Tahoma;
                            font-size: 11px; cursor: pointer;">
                            <div unselectable="on" style="width: 400px; margin-left: -1px; height: 2px; background-color: Blue;
                                font-size: 1px; position: relative;">
                            </div>
                            <div unselectable="on" style="width: 398px; height: 1px; background-color: #000000;
                                font-size: 1px; position: relative;">
                            </div>
                            <div unselectable="on" style="display: block; padding-left: 1px;">
                                Event 3
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td unselectable="off" onclick="javascript:alert('2012-04-01T00:00:00, B');" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFED95';"
                    onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFF4BC';" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
                    width: 19px; background-color: #FFF4BC; cursor: pointer;">
                    <div unselectable="on" style="display: block; width: 18px; height: 19px; border-right: 1px solid #EAD098;">
                        <!-- -->
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td unselectable="off" onclick="javascript:alert('2012-04-02T00:00:00, B');" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFED95';"
                    onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFD5';" style="border-bottom-width: 1px;
                    border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 20px; cursor: pointer;
                    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 213);">
                    <div unselectable="on" style="display: block; width: 19px; height: 19px; border-right: 1px solid #EAD098;">
                        <!-- -->
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td unselectable="off" onclick="javascript:alert('2012-04-03T00:00:00, B');" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFED95';"
                    onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFD5';" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
                    width: 20px; background-color: #FFFFD5; cursor: pointer;">
                    <div unselectable="on" style="display: block; width: 19px; height: 19px; border-right: 1px solid #EAD098;">
                        <!-- -->
                    </div>
                </td>
```

'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have just got the syntax of your filter a bit wrong. You need to use an ["attribute equals" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$( "table" ).selectable({
    filter: 'tbody td[unselectable="off"]'
});
```

Currently you are looking for any element of type `unselectable` that is a descendant of a `td` element, and using a pseudo-selector called `:off`, neither of which exists.

Comment: Thanx James. but color is not changing.. any idea.